# Animation - text get blurry when its start to scroll

Tags: html, css, animation

I have a auto scrolling div but i have one problem when it starting to scroll, the text get blurry Can someone help me about this?

sample picture.
[image]
here is my css

```
.events {

  animation: autoscroll 25s ease-in-out infinite;
  animation-delay: 2s;


}
.events:hover {
    -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
}
@keyframes autoscroll {
  from { 

    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);

  }
  to {
    transform: translate3d(0,-90%,0);
  }
```

}

Comment: Have you tried different browsers? I've noticed on Firefox that when you transform using CSS, text and images usually get blurry while the animation is playing. Perhaps try to use `translate()` instead of `translate3d()`

Comment: @amorten My current browser is chrome i haven't tried it on firefox. I tried your suggestion to change the 'translate3d()' to 'translate()' but didn't work.

Comment: Is your website online so I can see it in action?

Comment: @amorten not yet online bro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried mimicking what I get from your description in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/533ktdfv/).

The biggest difference is that you can try using the following properties for osx, though I didn't see any difference in my testing.

```
text-rendering: optimizeLegibility; // SVG property
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; // Font-smoothing on osx in Safari/Chrome
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale; // Font-smoothing on osx in Firefox
```

I tested the above fiddle in Firefox, Chrome and Safari and the text appears sharp in all. The only blur I noticed is from the response time in my monitor, so that may be what you're noticing as well.

Also, make sure to include support for all browsers in your `.events:hover {}` by including:

```
.events:hover {
    -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
    -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
    -o-animation-play-state: paused;
    animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

A good way to test for monitor blur would be to take a screenshot while it's animating and when it's not and then compare the two.